# Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting an error when trying to create a package with procedures inside it. I need to create a global cursor as well as 2 procedures and a function.

below is the question I am trying to answer.
Write a package called cursor_state that declares a global cursor as a join of 
EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS. The cursor should select every employee’s first and last name, department name, and the employee’s salary. The package should also contain three public procedures: the first one opens the cursor; the second one has an IN parameter of type NUMBER and fetches and displays a number of rows as well as the current value of the loop counter. The third procedure closes the cursor. Remember to test the state of the cursor before you try to open or close it within each procedure.

and the code I came up with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE cursor_state IS
CURSOR emp_curs IS
  SELECT first_name, last_name, department_name, salary
  FROM employees, departments
  WHERE employees.department_id = departments.department_id;

PROCEDURE open_curs;
FUNCTION fetch_rows RETURN BOOLEAN;
PROCEDURE close_curs;
END cursor_state;
```

And here is the creation of the BODY

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cursor_state IS 

PROCEDURE open_curs IS 
BEGIN 
  IF NOT emp_curs%ISOPEN THEN OPEN emp_curs; 
  END IF;
END open_curs; 

FUNCTION fetch_rows(n NUMBER := 1) RETURN BOOLEAN IS 
emp_first employees.first_name%TYPE, 
emp_last employees.last_name%TYPE, 
emp_dept employees.department_name%TYPE, 
emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE;



BEGIN 
  FOR count IN 1 .. n LOOP 
  FETCH emp_curs INTO emp_first, emp_last, emp_dept, emp_salary; 
  EXIT WHEN emp_curs%NOTFOUND; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE((emp_first), (emp_last), (emp_dept), (emp_salary)); 
  END LOOP; 
  RETURN emp_curs%FOUND; 
END fetch_rows; 

PROCEDURE close_curs IS 
BEGIN 
  IF emp_curs%ISOPEN
  THEN CLOSE emp_curs;
  END IF;

END close_curs; 

END cursor_state;
```

I have tried many attempts to change the semi colons and different places for the end statements. to no avail.

Comment: I seem to have missed some semi colons when declaring my variables. I will edit the OP to include the working code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has too many silly errors, I've corrected them. Observe carefully the changes.

**Package**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE cursor_state IS
CURSOR emp_curs IS
  SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_name, e.salary
    FROM employees e join departments d
  ON e.department_id = d.department_id;

  PROCEDURE open_curs;
  FUNCTION fetch_rows(n NUMBER DEFAULT 1) RETURN BOOLEAN;
  PROCEDURE close_curs;
END cursor_state;
/
```

**Package Body**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cursor_state IS

     PROCEDURE open_curs IS
     BEGIN
          IF NOT emp_curs%isopen THEN
               OPEN emp_curs;
          END IF;
     END open_curs;

     FUNCTION  fetch_rows(n NUMBER DEFAULT 1) RETURN BOOLEAN IS

          emp_first employees.first_name%TYPE;
          emp_last employees.last_name%TYPE;
          emp_dept departments.department_name%TYPE;
          emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE;
     BEGIN
         FOR count IN 1 .. n LOOP  
               FETCH emp_curs INTO
                    emp_first,emp_last,emp_dept,emp_salary;
               EXIT WHEN emp_curs%notfound;
               dbms_output.put_line(emp_first||','
                                    ||emp_last
                                    ||','
                                    ||emp_dept
                                    ||','
                                    ||emp_salary);

          END LOOP;

          RETURN emp_curs%found;
     END fetch_rows;

     PROCEDURE close_curs IS
     BEGIN
          IF emp_curs%isopen THEN
               CLOSE emp_curs;
          END IF;
     END close_curs;

END cursor_state;
/
```

**Execution**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
     x BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
     cursor_state.open_curs;
     x:=cursor_state.fetch_rows(5);
     cursor_state.close_curs;
END;
/
```

**Result**

```
Jennifer,Whalen,Administration,4400
Michael,Hartstein,Marketing,13000
Pat,Fay,Marketing,6000
Den,Raphaely,Purchasing,11000
Karen,Colmenares,Purchasing,2500


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use semicolon here (and use the departments type, since you join employees table with the departments table):

```
emp_first employees.first_name%TYPE;
emp_last employees.last_name%TYPE;
emp_dept departments.department_name%TYPE; 
emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE;
```

Concatenate by using the pipe symbol:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_first || ' ' || emp_last || ' ' || emp_dept || ' ' || emp_salary);
```

Define the same parametres in the package definition as in the package body:

```
FUNCTION fetch_rows(n NUMBER := 1) RETURN BOOLEAN;
```

Then try out your code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_ret BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  cursor_state.open_curs;
  l_ret := cursor_state.fetch_rows(2);
  cursor_state.close_curs;
END;
/
```

Example output:

```
Steven King Executive 24000
Neena Kochhar Executive 17000
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```